# Apache2 streaming over HTTP

Tags: apache-http-server, streaming, http

I have a server with lot of media files. Actually, I have an apache2 installed on the server, and I use it to do some streaming of video and audio files.

This is working fine, with status-code 206 Content-Partial.
But I have an issue, with video or audio, with HTML5 or browser-plugin, which I think is issued from Status-Code 206 content and how it is working.

Lot of times I want to directly play my movie at one hour, or just listen to 5 min at 30 min of a big audio file. The problem is always the same, I have to wait that everything until that moment is download.

What I want is to do some "smooth streaming" for all medias files, using HTML5 or browser plugins. By "smooth streaming", I hear that I could play any part of my media, without having to download everything before.

I have read a lot about streaming with apache2, but I have not find some general solution for the same problem.

Can I do this with only apache2 ?
Should I need to use another software, or writing some scripts myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing these are mp4 files. The files must have the moov box at the start of the file (I won't go into more detail here because it has been covered a lot over at stack overflow. Just search for it) . This can be done with a tool like qt-faststart from ffmpeg.

Comment: Sometimes it is mpeg, sometimes ogg sometimes avi etc ...

Comment: Those formats are not supported by html5.

Comment: Read my post, I have some plugins for my browser. I can play avi and ogg with firefox on my linux ...
It's not only about HTML5 ... It is about streaming in general with apache2

Comment: Well, then it totally depends on the plugin. Because every plugin is different, and every format is different. "Smooth Streaming" is a Microsoft standard that uses fragmented mp4 container with a silverlight client. Smooth streaming is no longer supported by Microsoft and being replaced by DASH. I did read your question. There is no such thing as "smooth streaming" for all medias files unless you transcode/transmux on the fly. And I would recommend that you just convert once instead of every playback if you are stuck with Apache.

Comment: Okay I did not know the exact signification of smooth streaming.
I think I can do it with some php script. I'(m gonna try.
Because my mozilla plugins can handle switching time in media with other servers.
That is why I am pretty sure I should improve server, and not plugins.
Thank you,